# HTML Checkbox cannot be checked

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, checkbox

I have some checkbox in a table that contains the id of that row item. I want to allow the user to select multiple rows. However, I can't seem to check the checkbox on Chrome. I loaded the site up on my mobile and it works. I have tried to insert an onclick but it doesn't seem like the checkbox is registering any clicks to it as well. Please help.

The table

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Events/Two/Search');?>
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-left">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Phone Number</td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                    if(!empty($datatable)){
                        foreach ($datatable as $data){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->first_name." ".$data->last_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->phone_number; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->address;?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

EDIT: I have cleared my cache and cookies as well. It works on the mobile but not on chrome for some reason.

EDIT 2 : It works on Safari

EDIT 3 : If I place a checkbox on another place, I can check it. Just not in the table

Comment: Do you have a `<form ....>` tag anywhere to start the form? `<input>` fields only work inside a `<form...>` tag

Comment: What result do you get on mobile with chrome and desktop with Chrome, IE, Firefox, ...?

Comment: I added the form tags. However it still doesn't work. Also, this works in Safari and on mobile

Comment: At the moment, I am unable to check anything. I click on it and no check appears. This is for Chrome on the desktop only.

Comment: Are you applying style to this code? Maybe some css is prevent the event

Comment: So far I've been using bootstraps default css. Nothing custom. My theme is sb-admin2

Comment: Yeah I've read through that. It doesn't work. Could it have something to do with placing checkboxes in tables?

Comment: Could it be a Chrome issue?

Comment: Yeah I've added it already

Comment: I discovered its probably something in the sb-admin theme thats stopping the checkboxes from being checked. Thanks so much  guys

Comment: Good news. Have you solved it yet?

Comment: I'll do that once I identify the item.

Answer (score -3):

```
<tbody>
                <?php 
                    if(!empty($datatable)){
                        foreach ($datatable->result() as $data){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->first_name." ".$data->last_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->phone_number; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->address;?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

First Your query is not working it seems so please preview this code the use jquery append to add more row if you need help on that code will be below

Jquery on click ADD/REMOVE ROW please Visit the link below
https://jsfiddle.net/susanadhikary/omngzss8/8/

Comment: susan?? the guy is already put how many hours to solve his problem who knows, and you are throwing random fiddle as answer??

Comment: first check the fiddle and tell me id its working or not his main problem i  check which is stop by query  foreach ($datatable->result() as $data){} after the query get working its will work and for append row in table my fiddle is 100% working other wise check yourself

Comment: At the moment jquery will not help me at all as I am unable to even select or check the box. I have tried to set an onclick action and that didnt even activate.